# Attempt to index upvalue which is a nil value

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The error "attempt to index upvalue 'askUser'(a nil value)" always shows up, I had to make the statement to a comment to run the app, how do i fix it?

```
function restartLvl()  
        for i = 1, #balloonTexts do
        display.remove(balloonTexts[i])
        print ("restart level")
    end
    score.text = '0'
    ballRemain.text = '3'
    balloonText = {}
    createBalloons(1, 3)
    if (askUser.isVisible == true) then --this is where the error occured
    askUser.isVisible = false
    end
    if (yesBtn.isVisible == true) then
    yesBtn.isVisible = false
    end
    if (noBtn.isVisible == true) then
    noBtn.isVisible = false
    end

    print("time from start: ", (system.getTimer()-gameTime))
    print('send mail')
    sendMail()
    restartBtn:removeEventListener('tap', restartLvl)

end
```

Comment: Can you show the code where `askUser` is created (and if exists, removed).

Answer (score 3):

The message is telling you that `askUser` is a local variable defined outside `restartLvl` and that `askUser` is nil and so cannot be indexed.

You'll have to find out why `askUser` is nil when you don't expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give askUser.isVisible a value.
Example:

```
askUser = blablabla
askUser.x = blablabla
aksUser.y = bablabla

askUser.isVisible = false

group:insert(askUser)
```

PS: Didn't know that there is an isVisible var :P 
I've always used `askUser.alpha = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Before removing your object from view check for nil

for example

```
 local try    --object on which you are working
    if(try==nil)then
       --do nothing
   else
      --do here what u want to do
   end
```

I was also getting same problem, in my case this is code working.